# Hook a check box to catch a fired event

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, mfc, hook

:-D Long story short, I would like to catch an event fired once the user sets checked to a dialog's check button of some windows (not my windows application). I understand little about hooking, but in this case as I would like to monitor an event (button-clicked), I don't know what message I should hook ? If you have any idea, please tell me, I appreciate any of your precious advice. Thank you.

Comment: So you want to listen for a window message occurring in some other, arbitrary application, that you don't have the source for, is that correct?

Comment: Also, you haven't specified what language you would like to do this in. More information will get you a more relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

[System-wide hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are what you are looking for. Don't expect a one-liner solution though!

Answer (score 0):

A solution on the road less traveled is to [inject a DLL](http://codepad.org/abSOfzGp), then [subclass the window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).